# How can we find different words in a file in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

In my project, I need to sort out a list in a file.txt file contains different words. I need my program to recognize this 3 names : bob, alicia and cookie. And each time when he found for exemple "cookie" I want to display "dog" as a result, for "alicia" "girl" and for "bob" "boy" and for an other word "unknown". And when there is a space the code should not take it into account.

So the input file is :

```
hello


shirley
cookie

bob
alicia
cook
road
alicia
stole
bob
```

My code :

```
//code in JavaScript


var texFile = "file.txt";
var file = new File (textFile);

file.open("r");
var str="";
while (!file.epf){

    //read each line of text
    str += file.readln()


file.close();
alert(str);


    switch (names){
    case "bob":
    console.log('boy');
    case "alicia":
    console.log('girl');
    case "cookie":
    console.log('dog');
    default:
    console.log('unknown');

    }

}
```

I have so many problem with this code, fist I don't know how can I make correctly the link between the `switch' and the file in order to research in the file correctly if the word exists inside or not. And after the second problem is about space in the input file, how my code can ignore it?

And the result I need it is :

```
unknown
unknown
dog
boy 
girl 
unknown
unknown
girl 
unknown
boy
```

So can you help me to understand correctly my errors please?

Answer (score 2):

[fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) is a core nodejs module.

You can use any other way to read the file.

The main thing is `str` should contain the file contents.

I split the contents by groups of whitespace characters, including new lines.

For each split elements I call a function which logs to console and uses the [conditional ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to do several if-else-if checks. You can use switch case here, but I prefer this one as more compact and readable.

```js
var fs = require('fs');
var str = fs.readFileSync('file.txt', 'utf8');

str.split(/\s+/).forEach(function (s) {
  console.log(
    s === 'bob'
      ? 'boy'
      : s === 'alicia'
      ? 'girl'
      : s === 'cookie'
      ? 'dog'
      : 'unknown'
  );
});
```

Comment: I tried to run your program, But there are some syntax error, and for me There are not syntax error and I don't know why, I have this  result on my terminal : `syntax error
js: str.split(/\s+/).forEach(s =>`  Can you help me to understand this king of error please ?

Comment: @ShirleyTruffier-Blanc I removed a lambda operator so it would comply to es5 syntax.
Possibly this was the problem.
Unfortunately I can't say for sure because your comment shows only the line where error is and not the error text.
Also I added a bit more of explanations.
Please try running this version and ask if there are questions.

Answer (score 1):

First add a separator between file lines and use if statment to check if the line contain word

```
 //read each line of text
 if(file.readln().trim()!='')
 {
     str += ','+file.readln();
 }
```

Create array from your str

```
var words=str.split(',');
```

Use foreach loop to get each word from you words array

```
words.forEach(function(word){
    switch (word){
        case "bob":
        console.log('boy');
        case "alicia":
        console.log('girl');
        case "cookie":
        console.log('dog');
        default:
        console.log('unknown');
      }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help I tried to you it but there is an error like `js: uncaught JavaScript runtime exception: ReferenceError: "File" is not defined.` I tired to find a solution online but I failed. Can you help me please?